# Rendering a UIWebView before it's parent ViewController is displayed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

My iOS/iPhone app starts with a login page (a little like the login page on the Facebook app). There's an info button at the bottom that flips the first view controller onto another that gives a little info about the app to anyone before they login.

What I'm struggling with is that I'm using a UIWebView to display my few paragraphs of body text and a picture, however it's contents is filled in on 'viewDidLoad'. This means that momentarily when I'm 'flipping' between the ViewControllers the info page is blank and only gets filled with my content when the animation is complete.

I have tried setting up the UIWebView inside `initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` with no luck.

Does anyone have any idea how to render it/have it ready for when it is visible? It looks fine  if I leave it and then flip back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can "force" the call of the  viewDidLoad of the second ViewController in the first with:

[secondViewController view];

with this you can avoid to wait for loading the webview

Comment: Perfect answer thanks. I have sat here for the past few hours and worked out how to do UIViewControllers programmatically rather than using the storyboard. It was all setup and I called the method as you suggested (from App Delegate). Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, why not render the second view when the app loads or in the background after the first VC loads and have it hidden, then make it visible it when the user presses the button?

Or maybe just render the webview in the first view controller then pass it to the second view controller when the user presses the button.

Comment: I would do your first suggestion, but I'm using storyboards. My second viewcontroller is initialized and 'viewdidload' as it comes into view. Could I hook this up programmatically and link it to my storyboard? (to be honest I use the story board less and less).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the option `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent` for the flip animation?